# delete function become show function when i apply my custom layout to the pay in rals4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout

After I create my posts controller and CRUD function,and start rails server,it will be OK.but when i create my own layout "posts.html.erb" in app/views/layouts directory instead of the default layout "application.html.erb". The delete method disabled and the function is the same as the show method. My own layout content is:

```
Hello,World!
<%= yield %>
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: What is the delete link for the post, in your layout, can you please share it?

Comment: <td><%= link_to "Delete", post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are You Sure？"} %></td>

Comment: Strange issue!!... Ok.. just try with <td><%= link_to "Delete", post_path(post), :method => "DELETE", :confirm => "Are You Sure？" %></td>

Comment: It is the same result

Comment: the link to delete might be inside a form. Just put it aside.

Comment: if so,why is it OK when using default application layout?

Answer (score 0):

it's because you're not including jquery (or some other compatible js lib) in your custom layout as opposed to the default layout. the data parameters inside the link are processed by javascript unobtrusively. if not, then you just get a plain old link to your post which will end up in the show action.

try adding

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

to the top of your custom layout file (or whatever is in the default layout file).

you may need `csrf_meta_tags` as well, not sure